Kali Linux WSL 2 Windows Terminal wlan0
I downloaded Kali Linux WSL 2 Terminal to my Windows 10.
However, it is not showing wlan0 even though I'm connected to the internet.
Is there a way to solve this, or is my Wi-Fi adapter not compatible?
Error: airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces

wifi      = none (no device)


What isn't showing wlan0? What is this thing showing instead? Why are you expecting to see wlan0? What hardware is this? Please explain what you are doing here. Also, please consider NOT using Kali. I believe Windows also provides an Ubuntu image, why not use that? Kali is not supposed to be used as a regular system, it is a specialist tool designed for professional pen testers and absolutely the worst place to start learning.

It's not showing the wifi thingy idk. I edited the post. And I also have Ubuntu, but wanted to try Kali.

Please don't undo helpful edits. The bold is distracting and you even brought back a spelling error! "Thought" is not the word you want here, you want "though".

Huh? did i undo something? (sorry if i did im used to reddit and 4chan style posts)

You won't see wlan0 because Windows is already using it. All you get in WSL is a generic network connection

Ohhhhh okay. Is there a way to route that to the terminal (?) (i have no idea what im talking about but im still gonna post.)

In WSL? I don't believe so

Ok. I'm just gonna buy a new laptop i guess. Thanks!

It would be cheaper to buy a compatible USB WiFi adapter and run VirtualBox. Lots of questions (and answers) here on doing that

@ChrisDavies does the WSL Kali thing even support networking? Or does it ship with networking disabled like the normal Kali?

@terdon running Kali on WSL now. I see what feels like a virtualised generic ethernet interface with a private IP address. My Windows host provides a gateway with NAT - the Kali interface is not bridged to my LAN and therefore I suspect it can neither sniff nor play with ARP spoofing, etc. It certainly does not see my physical WiFi device. Ping me in chat if you want more details for information
